# Should relational tables contain duplicate data to speed up queries

Tags: php, mysql, indexing, database-design, database-performance

I have a MySQL database with 4 tables:

```
job
job_application
client
candidate
```

Each table has it's own primary key, i.e `job_id`, `job_application_id`, `client_id`, `candidate_id`

Employers in the `client` table can post jobs in the `job` table. The `job` table contains a `client_id` field which identifies the client

Candidates in the `candidate` table can apply for a job, inserting a row in to the `job_application` table. The `job_application` table contains a `job_id` field and a `candidate_id` field to identify what the job is and who applied for it

I've run in to a bit of a problem writing up the queries for Employers to manage the job applications they receive. As an example here is a function I wrote that deletes rows from `job_application`

```
public function deleteJobApplications($job_application_ids) {
    $this->db->query("DELETE ja.* FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "job_application ja LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "job j ON (j.job_id = ja.job_id) WHERE ja.job_application_id IN ('" . implode("','", array_map('intval', $job_application_ids)) . "') AND j.client_id = '" . (int)$this->client->getClientId() . "'");
}
```

Because the `client_id` is only referenced in the `job` table, I need to `LEFT JOIN` the `job` table every time I want to `UPDATE` or `DELETE` from the `job_application` table

Should I add another `client_id` field to the `job_application` table, essentially duplicating data already held in the database, or continue with the `LEFT JOIN` for every `UPDATE` and `DELETE`?

Comment: Having redundant data for the sake of speed and complexity minimization is not alien to databases the key is balance

Comment: i would say duplicating foreign keys is a proper practice for improving performance in databases, ofc you have to make sure to keep the tables consistent. try some performance tests (huge amounts of datasets) and see if it helps you a lot

Comment: I think you should checkout the indexex, do some "explain ", I did left join on tables with +100m rows, in less then a milisecond (the avarage was ~4ms), on a decent server, not high tech. I don't think you have that many rows, and a left join should work just fine.

Comment: `Cross referenced` table is typical case that contains foreign keys. And indexing can make a huge table faster. So you may check on those. +1 Radu

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do here but deletion of the jobs should be by `jobID`.. Client can delete a job or update it and `job_application` table should process the `jobID` of that particular request. Is there any particular reason why you cant use `jobID`?

Comment: @BhrugeshPatel You misread the question. It's for deletion of job application entries, not the jobs themselves

Comment: @Andy Yes, I understand that you are working on job applications but they are still attached to a job, right? Like job Developer (ID : 10).. Employed selects a profile then use jobID + applicantID to approve and jobID to deny rest or whatever you are doing. (Most probably archive them since deleting is usually considered a bad practice). I dont see why you would need clientID.

Comment: @BhrugeshPatel you need a client id becuase otherwise ANY client would be able to delete ANY job application whether it belongs to a job posted by them or not simply by modifying the HTTP request

Comment: Right, I didnt consider the HTTP request jacking scenario.. Well, in that case, you can add the ID. It's an ID so it will not jeopardize the integrity of the data because ID never change.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it looks like you are trying to delete from a result table that's calculated by joining tables together.  Don't do that.  Make your delete reference a single table.  You can use a subquery in the WHERE clause to figure out which rows need to be deleted.

Comment: @WalterMitty So a subquery would be better performance wise than a join in this case?

Comment: I can't speak to MySQL.  For the DBMS products that I know, delete and join won't work together, period.

Comment: @WalterMitty I'm not sure what you mean by won't work together as this is the method I currently use and it works as expected. I just don't know whether as the dataset gets bigger the performance is gonna suck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem *isn't* that you need to denormalize "job_applications" by introducing the "client_id" as a redundant column. (The currently accepted answer is factually incorrect in that regard.) Your problem is that you didn't normalize correctly in the first place. If you *had*, the column "client_id" would *already* be in that table, and your problem would never have arisen in the first place.

Let's pretend that candidate names, client names, and job names are globally unique.

A table that looks like this will satisfy the predicate Person named "candidate_name" applies for "job_name" at company "client_name".

```
job_applicatons
Person named <candidate_name> applies for <job_name> at company <client_name>.

client_name  job_name                candidate_name  
--
Microsoft    C++ programmer, Excel   Ed Wood 
Microsoft    C++ programmer, Excel   Dane Crute 
Microsoft    C++ programmer, Excel   Vim Winder
Microsoft    C++ programmer, Word    Wil Krug
Microsoft    C++ programmer, Word    Val Stein
Google       Python coder, search    Ed Wood
Google       Programmer, compilers   Ed Wood
Google       Programmer, compilers   Val Stein
```

Three columns, no id numbers, no nulls, no nonprime attributes, all key. This relation is in 6NF.

It should be obvious that you could create a table for jobs (or job offers) by selecting distinct values from the first two columns. The foreign key reference is obvious.

```
jobs
Company named <client_name> offers <job_name>.

client_name  job_name
--
Microsoft    C++ programmer, Excel
Microsoft    C++ programmer, Word
Google       Python coder, search
Google       Programmer, compilers
```

In a similar way, you can select distinct values from the first column alone for a set of companies, and from the last column alone for a set of applicants.  Again, the foreign key references should be obvious.

```
clients
Company named <client_name> is a client.

client_name
--
Microsoft
Google

candidates
Person named <candidate_name> is looking for a job.

candidate_name  
--
Ed Wood 
Dane Crute 
Vim Winder
Wil Krug
Val Stein
```

All those tables are in 6NF.

Augmenting a table with a surrogate key in addition to its natural keys doesn't change the normal form when you do it correctly. Let's replace the natural keys in "job_applications" with your surrogate ID numbers.  Making that replacement will result in your table looking like this.  (In practice, you'd do the same thing in the other tables, too.)

```
job_applications
--
client_id
job_id
candidate_id
primary key (client_id, job_id, candidate_id)
other columns go here...
```

Note that client_id is already in there. If there are no other columns, you're still in at least 5NF.

Comment: I appreciate the time and effort you have put in to this but it doesn't answer the question of should I add another client_id to the job_application table to improve the performance of UPDATE's and DELETE's?

Comment: If you had normalized your tables to 5NF to start with, it would already be there. See the table "job_applications" above.

Comment: Ok...still not actually answering my original question though. Thanks anyway

Comment: Your original question (and the answer you accepted) are based on a flawed understanding of normalization. I updated my answer in order to make it more clear.

Comment: Excellent. The updated answer is very helpful thank you. I've changed the accepted answer to this one

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question it depends your case, in particular size of tables if it is worth or not.
This process is called denormalization.
eg you can have info here :
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization

Comment: The OP's problem is not that he needs to denormalize for performance. The problem is that he failed to normalize correctly in the first place. And you did, too.

Comment: Yes I failed to answer, the title of the question "Should relational tables contain duplicate data to speed up queries" was misleading for me, I answered with the title of the question that is non specific so I answsered a non specific answer which was not needed there.